# How to place two divs side by side

Tags: html, css

how will i place these to divs side by side i have looked online and in other forums but they seemed a bit to confusing because my code is creating a "paper" effect and theirs is not so im really stuck at this moment.. does any body know how to do this? i have a jsfiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/c6gus/2/)

this site it making me post code to include a js fiddle so here is the code

```
/** Playstation **/
.info, .info:before, .info:after
{
background-color: blue;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.infops
{
position: relative;
width: 50%;
padding: 2em;
margin: 50px auto;
}

.infops:before, .infops:after
{
content: "";
 position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-transform: rotateZ(2.5deg);
-o-transform: rotate(2.5deg);
transform: rotateZ(2.5deg);
z-index: -1;
}

.infops:after
{
 -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-2.5deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-2.5deg);
transform: rotateZ(-2.5deg);
}

.infops h1
{
  font-size: 1.8em;
 font-weight: normal;
text-align: center;
padding: 0.2em 0;
margin: 0;
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}

.infops p
{
text-align: left;
margin: 1.5em 0;
}
/**xbox**/
.infoxbox, .infoxbox:before, .infoxbox:after
{
background-color: orange;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.infoxbox
{
position: relative;
width: 50%;
padding: 2em;
margin: 50px auto;
}

.infoxbox:before, .infoxbox:after
{
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-transform: rotateZ(2.5deg);
-o-transform: rotate(2.5deg);
transform: rotateZ(2.5deg);
z-index: -1;
}

.infoxbox:after
{
-webkit-transform: rotateZ(-2.5deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-2.5deg);
transform: rotateZ(-2.5deg);
}

.infoxbox h1
{
font-size: 1.8em;
font-weight: normal;
text-align: center;
padding: 0.2em 0;
margin: 0;
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}

.infoxbox p
{
text-align: left;
margin: 1.5em 0;
}
```

And here is my html

```
<div class="infoxbox">
<h1>Xbox</h1>

</div>
<div class="info">
<h1>Playstation</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: I had to edit a few things, i accidently posted before i was done

Comment: add ps to the second div class please so Playstation get's the style's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
    .infops {float:left;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c6gus/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c6gus/3/ i want xbox on the left and playstation on the right so would i add .infops {float:right;}

Comment: you can just do it like it's on the fiddle. but i guess you have already seen it.

Answer (score 2):

What about `float: left` to `infops` div?

Comment: just to that div or both?

Comment: i just did that in my jsfiddle and it glitched out the page

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display:inline-block` to both the divs

```
.infoxbox{
     display:inline-block
}

.info{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c6gus/8/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display:inline-block`. I have used inline style attribute for demo

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c6gus/7/)

Comment: i forgot to add ps to the second div class name so they both are styled when i added it it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use `float: left` for one side and `float:right` for the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use tables:

```
<table width="100%">
<td>
<div class="infoxbox">

<h1>Xbox</h1>

</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="infops">

<h1>Playstation</h1>

</div>
</td>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c6gus/15/

Comment: im going to use the tables for something in the div but +1 for the good idea

Answer (score 0):

```
.infoxbox{display: inline-block;}
.infops{display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: didnt change a thing in my jsfiddle

Comment: Shouldn't there be dots before _infobox_ and _infops_?